# Authenticating Users without Account Linking Google Action

Tags: actions-on-google

I am attempting to create a Google Action that links to a Libraries resources and allows patrons to retrieve information about their accounts, access the catalog, and place holds.  One of the requirements is to have a Google speaker in the library that patrons can walk up to, verbally sign in with their credentials, and then utilize the libraries resources.

All of this functionality works.  However, it failed the review process because Google wants me to "implement account linking api" to link patron's accounts to their Google accounts.  This (as far as I can tell,) directly contradicts the goal of the project to have a device that anyone can walk up to to sign in with.

My method is indeed against their Policies for Actions on Google. (https://developers.google.com/actions/policies/general-policies#financial_services)

Does anyone have any ideas on how I might achieve the ability to have patrons walk up to a device and sign in while not violating Google's Policies?

Comment: In a public setting of that sort, there's no easy way to verbally authenticate. I'd argue that you shouldn't do that, as saying a password aloud is an anti-pattern that others can easily hear. For the sake of security, you may want to take another look at how your action should behave.

Comment: You are not wrong. However, the desired functionality is as stated, "the ability to have patrons walk up to a device and sign in."  If you have suggestions on how to do that with a Google Home device without verbal credential input, that would be helpful.